# How to change a background on a single word in a paragraph in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a text frame in which I want to emphasize certain words by making reversing  their colors (black on white background, in this case). I know that it's an option for an entire frame or a paragraph, but I can't seem to figure out how to set it for a single word.

That's what I'm aiming for:

[image: That's pretty much what I'm aiming for]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really have a background color on a single word, *but* there is an easy workaround:

Simply use a *Character Style* to create a thick *Underline*. Here is an example:

[image]

If you want a left and right margin, I'm afraid you'll have to add a *White Space* before and after each highlighted word.